# React Hooks: toggle element on map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

See that loop loading two components. I would like to display only `<Image />` by default, but when I click this element, I want it to turn into `<YouTube />` (only the one I press, the others are still `<Image />`). I can do this on a class component, but I want to use a hook

```
export const MusicVideos = () => {
  const [selectedVideo, setVideo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
          {videos.map(video => (
<div key={video.id}>
             <Image  src={video.image} hover={video.hover} alt="thumbnail" />
            <YouTube link={video.link} />
</div>
          ))}
   </Wrapper/>
  );
};
```

Comment: videos.map((video, index) => { return (<>{selectedVideo === index ? <image onClick={() => setVideo(index)}/> : <youtube/> </>) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component like this and pass it to the loop;

```
const YouTubeToggle = (video) => {

    const [selectedVideo, setVideo] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div key={video.id}>
            {selectedVideo == 0 &&
                <Image  src={video.image} onClick={() => setVideo(!selectedVideo)} hover={video.hover} alt="thumbnail" />
            }
            {selectedVideo != 0 &&
                <YouTube link={video.link} />
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export const MusicVideos = () => {
  const [selectedVideo, setVideo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
          {videos.map(video => (
            <YouTubeToggle video={video} />
          ))}
   </Wrapper/>
  );
};
```

Comment: why are you using 0 instead of false?

Answer (score 1):

you can bind onClick for your image and setVideo to video.id and compare with video.id to render image or video.

```
export const MusicVideos = () => {
  const [selectedVideo, setVideo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
          {videos.map(video => (
            {selectedVideo !== video.id ?
             <Image onClick={() => setVideo(video.id)  src={video.image} hover={video.hover} alt="thumbnail" /> :
             <YouTube link={video.link} />
          ))}
   </Wrapper/>
  );
};
```